# How do you stop OS X from rebooting when developing OpenGL code

Tags: macos, opengl

I'm currently writing an OpenGL renderer on my 2011 13" MacBook Pro with a Sandybridge graphics chip.

I'm finding that I'm encountering a lot of kernel panics and reboots when developing OpenGL code. Frequently, whenever I have an error, my system just reboots, rather than gives me chance to catch the error and retrieve an error code.

I know that it is related to the graphics driver as the resultant problem reporting app displayed at reboot identifies it as the entity that crashed.

The specific issue seems closely related to texture creation. Clearly there is some bug in my code, but regardless, this really shouldn't be rebooting the OS under a high-level API like OpenGL.

Does OS X have any kind of debug mode functionality that I might enable, similar to that of D3D, so that I can catch the error earlier, rather than have to use russian roulette debugging?

(I'm aware of the OpenGL profiler, Driver Monitor and so on, yet have had little success with using these tools to catch these sorts of problems)

Comment: With "OpenGL renderer" you mean an application that links and makes use of OpenGL—or do you develop a graphics driver component running in the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, OpenGL Profiler is the tool to use. You should check the box marked, "Break on VAR error" and "break on thread error," at least. If you have trouble with it, let me know and I might be able to help. (I'm no expert but have had some luck with it.)

Beyond that, the crashes you're seeing are probably related to you giving a pointer to OpenGL, and it attempting to read or write memory from that pointer, but the pointer is bad (or the length of the data is wrong). If it's texture related, then perhaps you're attempting to upload or download a texture and passing the wrong width and height, or have the wrong format. I've seen this happen when passing an incorrect number of elements to glDrawElements(). I was confused about whether an "element" was a vertex or an actual object (like a QUAD or TRIANGLE) when it happened to me. The VAR error reporting helped me find that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to come back to this for anyone looking... it turns out, that the problem was entirely related to failing to set the current context as different threads begun issuing OpenGL commands.

So, each thread needed to lock a mutex, set the open gl context, and then begin its work. It would then release the context and then the lock, guaranteeing non-simultaneous access to the one OpenGL context.

So, no deeply unknown behaviour here really, just an inexperienced newbie not fully implementing the guidelines out there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Others have responded with potential workarounds. But note that your application should never be able to cause the machine to panic (which these days simply reboots the machine and presents a dialog to submit the report to Apple).

At a minimum, you should send the report to Apple. Additionally, you should file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com including the panic log, a system profiler report, and any details you can provide about how to reproduce (ideally, a sample app binary and/or source code). Filing your own bug report will help in many ways -- prioritizing your bug (dupes bump priority), providing reproduction steps in case the problem & fix aren't obvious from the backtrace in the panic report, and opening a channel between you and Apple in case they need more information from you to track it down.